# How to insert many forms in db using Datatables

Tags: codeigniter, insert, datatables

I tried to submit many forms with datatables. User has to choose the number ot input rows, in which he can submit some information - it's something like Phpmyadmin when you insert rows in db. Names of the input rows are the same. I use loop to show many rows. But in this way with nested foreach, when I submit info in two rows, in database there are 8 rows. How to do that? 
Here's my view:

```html
echo form_open('admin/add_questions/');
?>
<table id='example'>
  <thead>
   <tr><th>Question</th><th>Code</th><th>Group</th><th>Is_reverse</th></tr>
  </thead>  
  <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>                             
            </tr>
        </tfoot> 
  <tbody>
  <?php for($i=0; $i<=20; $i++) {
   ?>
    <tr>
    <td>
     <input type="text" name="question[]" id="add_question_table" />
    </td><td>
     <input type="text" name="code[]" id="add_question_table" />
    </td><td>
     <input type="text" name="group[]" id="add_question_table" />
    </td><td>
     <input type="text" name="is_reverse[]" id="add_question_table" />
    </td></tr>
    <?php 
   }

    ?>

  </tbody>
  </table>
```

My Model is:

```html
<?php
class Admin_model extends CI_model {
 public function __construct() {
        parent:: __construct();
        $this->load->database();
        $this->load->library('session'); 
    }

    public function add_questions() {
        
        $date = new DateTime("now"); 
        foreach($this->input->post('question') as $v) {  

            foreach($this->input->post('code') as $f) { 
                foreach($this->input->post('group') as $val) {  

     $data = array(
            'question'=>$v ,
           'code'=>$f,
             'survey_id'=>$this->uri->segment(3), 
            'group_id'=>$val, 
 'created_at'=>$date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')    
        );
        $this->db->insert('survey_questions',$data);
 }
         
     }
 }
```

What's the way to do it? :)

Comment: It would be helpful if you would post controller code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi from my perspective its best to pass $_POST as a parameter to your add_questions() model method. You may try the following approach :)

```html
//controller code
$this->admin_model->add_questions($_POST);

//model code
function add_questions($data=array())
{
  if(count($data) > 0)
  {
    $date = new DateTime("now"); 
    for($i=0;$i<count($data['question']);$i++){
      $insert = array();
      $insert['question'] = $data['question'][$i]; 
      $insert['code'] = $data['code'][$i]; 
      $insert['survey_id'] = $data['survey_id'][$i]; 
      $insert['group_id'] = $data['group_id'][$i]; 
      $insert['created_at'] = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
      $this->db->insert('survey_questions',$insert);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It's perfect now! :) :)